# Full Calendar momentTimezone issue

Tags: javascript, timezone, fullcalendar, momentjs

I've been wrestling with this for a while now, so reaching out for a bit of help, please.
Here I am trying to get Full Calendar with 'momentTimezone' to maintain the time zone no matter what's the client system time zone is. So I just simply use time-zones.html file from the full calendar folder for testing purpose and I included moment js files('moment', 'moment-timezone').

So when I run the File. It's throwing an error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiDaX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3A7B.png)

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='../packages/core/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/daygrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/timegrid/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='../packages/list/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='../packages/core/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/moment/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/moment-timezone/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/interaction/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/daygrid/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/timegrid/main.js'></script>
<script src='../packages/list/main.js'></script>

<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var initialTimeZone = 'America/New_York';
    var timeZoneSelectorEl = document.getElementById('time-zone-selector');
    var loadingEl = document.getElementById('loading');
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [ 'moment','momentTimezone','interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list' ],
      timeZone: initialTimeZone,
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
      },
      defaultDate: '2019-08-12',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      selectable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: [
        {
          title: 'All Day Event',
          start: '2019-08-01'
        },
        {
          title: 'Long Event',
          start: '2019-08-07',
          end: '2019-08-10'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2019-08-09T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          groupId: 999,
          title: 'Repeating Event',
          start: '2019-08-16T16:00:00'
        },
        {
          title: 'Conference',
          start: '2019-08-11',
          end: '2019-08-13'
        },
        {
          title: 'Meeting',
          start: '2019-08-12T10:30:00',
          end: '2019-08-12T12:30:00'
        }          
      ],
      loading: function(bool) {
        if (bool) {
          loadingEl.style.display = 'inline'; // show
        } else {
          loadingEl.style.display = 'none'; // hide
        }
      },

      eventTimeFormat: { hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', timeZoneName: 'short' },

      dateClick: function(arg) {
        console.log('dateClick', calendar.formatIso(arg.date));
      },
      select: function(arg) {
        console.log('select', calendar.formatIso(arg.start), calendar.formatIso(arg.end));
      }
    });

    calendar.render();

    // load the list of available timezones, build the <select> options
    // it's HIGHLY recommended to use a different library for network requests, not this internal util func
    FullCalendar.requestJson('GET', 'php/get-time-zones.php', {}, function(timeZones) {

      timeZones.forEach(function(timeZone) {
        var optionEl;

        if (timeZone !== 'UTC') { // UTC is already in the list
          optionEl = document.createElement('option');
          optionEl.value = timeZone;
          optionEl.innerText = timeZone;
          timeZoneSelectorEl.appendChild(optionEl);
        }
      });
    }, function() {
      // TODO: handle error
    });

    // when the timezone selector changes, dynamically change the calendar option
    timeZoneSelectorEl.addEventListener('change', function() {
      calendar.setOption('timeZone', this.value);
    });
  });

</script>  
</head>
<body>

  <div id='top'>

    <div class='left'>
      Timezone:
      <select id='time-zone-selector'>
        <option value='local' selected>local</option>
        <option value='UTC'>UTC</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class='right'>
      <span id='loading'>loading...</span>
      <span id='script-warning'><code>php/get-events.php</code> must be running.</span>
    </div>

    <div class='clear'></div>

  </div>

  <div id='calendar'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like you installed the fullCalendar plugins for moment and moment-timezone, but did you actually install the original momentJS and moment-timezone libraries as well? They will be required dependencies.

Comment: @ADyson - i understood that using moment-timezone overlap the standard moment, and therefore its not needed?

Comment: "i understood that using moment-timezone overlap the standard moment"...very possibly, but as far as I can see you haven't installed either of them. All you've installed is the fullcalendar plugins which link to those main libraries.